# How to read 一人 and 人 in those sentences

Tags: readings

> いいからトムを一人にしておいてあげなさい。

I've found this sentence on tatoeba.org and the furigana they use for 一人 is いちにん。
Isn't it wrong? Shouldn't it be ひとり?

Same doubt with this sentence:

> いい人です

with which they use the furigana じん

Shouldn't it be ひと? Is it a matter of soud? I have to admit that いいひと doesn't sound so fluent...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a mistake on a page of questionable credibility. I don't know, but I guess some of the *furigana* might have been generated by computer software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay assured; You are correct on both accounts.

To say "to leave (someone) alone" = 「(someone) + を一人にする」, 「一人」 is always read 「ひとり」.

To describe a quality of a person by saying "(adjective) + 人", 「人」 is always read 「ひと」.

Comment: And tatoeba.org will be definitely canceled from my bookmarks. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Clover In case it's not clear, I believe l'electeur is saying 一人 is always read as ひとり in this situation.  In special situations, it can be read as いちにん, as in 一人前 (いちにんまえ、a portion for 1 person, used when ordering at a restaurant).